# SQL, limit the amout of times something can be added

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have made a library management system using Postgresql and I would like to limit the number of books a student/employee is able to borrow. If someone wants to add a new tuple where a student/employee has borrowed a book, and that particular user has already borrowed for example 7 books, the table won't accept another addition.

Comment: You could handle that with an INSERT trigger. But I would do that kind of checking in the program logic and not in SQL

Answer (score 1):

According to me, either you need to handle this from business logic perspective i.e before insert retrieve the data of a specific student and then take action

or

From a Rule-based perspective

1. Do not wait for any additional rows to be inserted by the application, but, constantly watch the table for the count, upon reaching the count, db notifies the app instead.
2. You can call/trigger a stored procedure based on the
   number of books taken by a specific user, if count_num_books > 7
   then, the app would handle it.

Please take a look at ON CONFLICT as mentioned in their document

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/

You can create a stored procedure with insert on conflict and take action accordingly.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column_list) VALUES(value_list)
ON CONFLICT target action;
```

Comment: That's not what she/he is asking for

Answer (score 0):

In general, SQL does not make this easy.  The typical solution is something like this:

- Keep a table with one row per book borrowed and student.
- Keep a count of outstanding books in the `students` table.
- Maintain this count using triggers.
- Add a check constraint on the count.

Postgres does have more convenient methods.  One method is to store the list of borrowed books as an array or in a JSON structure.  Alas, this is not a relational format.  And, it doesn't allow the declaration of foreign key constraints.

That said, it does allow a simple `check` constraint on the `books_borrowed` column -- by using `cardinality()` for instance.  And it doesn't make it easy to validate that there are no duplicates in the array.  Also, `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, and `DELETE`s are more complicated.

For your particular problem, I would recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the best place for this the APPLICATION checking. But otherwise perhaps this is a case where the easiest method is doing nothing - ie don't try keeping a running total number of active checkouts. As Postgres has no issue with a trigger selecting from the table firing the trigger just derive the outstanding books checked out. The following assumes the existence of an checkout table as:

```
create table checkouts    
     ( checkout_id          serial
     , student_employee_id  integer not null
     , book_id              integer not null
     , out_date             date    not null
     , return_date          date    default null
     ) ;
```

Then create an Insert row trigger on this table and call the following:

```
 create or replace function limit_checkouts()
   returns trigger 
   language plpgsql
 as $$
 declare
    checkout_count integer; 
 begin
    select count(*)
      into checkout_count
      from checkouts c
     where c.student_employee_id = new.student_employee_id
       and returned_date is null ;

    if checkout_count > 7
    then 
        raise exception 'Checkout limit exceeded';
    end if;

    return new;
end; 
$$;
```